# How to replace all occurrences of an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

If my array is gave me:
`["ITEM_1", "ITEM_2", "ITEM_3"]`

How I can remove the part `ITEM_` to get only `["1", "2", "3"]` ?

Comment: `["ITEM_1", "ITEM_2", "ITEM_3"].map(e => e.replace('ITEM_', ''))`

Comment: You can use regex to extract number https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_régulières

Comment: @qatari, do you want to modify the initial array?

Answer (score 3):

or:

```
var arr = ["ITEM_1", "ITEM_2", "ITEM_3"].map(function(item){
return item.split('_')[1];
});
```

or:

```
var arr = ["ITEM_1", "ITEM_2", "ITEM_3"].map(function(item){
return item.replace('ITEM_', '');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```js
console.log(
  ["ITEM_1", "ITEM_2", "ITEM_3"].join().match(/\d+/g)
)
```